# BB 10 Credit Card payment Throught Paypal

Tags: blackberry-10

I have a small question in my mind, can we make a credit cart payment using Paypal gateway Integration with in BB 10? I found in the link that https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/, PayPal provides Integration for Android and IOS. But I could not found the integration for BB 10.what i am thinking is may be site was not updated(we know BB 10 is a newly Released into market).my Question is Is it possible to Payment through Paypal Gateway in BB 10. If not can anybody suggest me any other way to achieve this in BB 10. Thanks in advance...

Comment: If BB10 is like BB7 then look for the Java section on the IPN API examples

Comment: hello Jordan doyle,Thanks for your quick reply. BB 10 supports C++ for coding but not java.Any other way to do so...

Comment: @Sharath hey... Did you got any other way ??

Comment: No, Not Yet !!! Still looking for Other Options